# Angular Firebase Storage, Assigning User Input Properties to Real Time Database

Tags: html, angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to upload a file especially an image to my firebase storage. I found a tutorial from this [link](http://javasampleapproach.com/frontend/angular/angular-4-firebase-upload-file-to-storage). I added the more properties like url and file to my existing class and i followed the function template on that link. But apparently i did something wrong. The file uploaded to  my storage and the console log didn't return any error. I need help with assigning another properties like `prdName`, `prdCategory`, and `prdSup` with user input correctly. Can someone help me with this please?

[image]

```js
//product.ts

export class Product {
  $prdKey: string;
  prdName: string;
  prdCategory: string; //Category
  prdSup: string; //supplier
  prdDescription: string;

  prdImage: string; //name
  prdUrl: string; //url
  file: File;

  constructor(file: File) {
    this.file = file;
  }
}
```

```js
//service.ts
variable: any;
selectedProduct: Product = new Product(this.variable); //-->there was an error here that said expected 1 argument but got 0 so i add variable:any;

private basePath = '/product';

pushFileToStorage(Product: Product, progress: {
  percentage: number
}) {
  const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
  const uploadTask = storageRef.child(`${this.basePath}/${Product.file.name}`).put(Product.file);

  uploadTask.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
    (snapshot) => {
      // in progress
      const snap = snapshot as firebase.storage.UploadTaskSnapshot
      progress.percentage = Math.round((snap.bytesTransferred / snap.totalBytes) * 100)
    },
    (error) => {
      // fail
      console.log(error)
    },
    () => {
      // success
      /*--What should i assign here?--*/
      Product.prdName = Product.file.name,
      Product.prdCategory = Product.file.name,
      Product.prdSup = Product.file.name,
      Product.prdDescription = Product.file.name,
      /*------------------------------------------*/
      Product.prdUrl = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL,
      Product.prdImage = Product.file.name,
      
      this.saveFileData(Product)
    }
  );
}

private saveFileData(Product: Product) {
  this.firebase.list(`${this.basePath}/`).push(Product);
}
```

```js
//component.ts

upload() {
  const file = this.selectedFiles.item(0);
  this.currentFileUpload = new Product(file);
  this.ProductService.pushFileToStorage(this.currentFileUpload, this.progress);
}
```

```html
<!--component.html-->
<!--form snippet-->
<form #productForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="upload()">
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Product Name</label>
  <input class="form-control" name="prdName" #prdName="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="ProductService.selectedProduct.prdName">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button> 
</form>
```

Please let me know if more snippets are needed. Thank you in advance.

(Update)
I put the push function inside `//success` condition, however i'm not sure what to assign for each class properties. `Product.prdName = Product.file.name,` will give me `prdName` equal to the file name. I tried `Product.prdName = selectedProduct.prdName,` but looks like it is not correct.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a very efficient debugging mechanism. Did you already step through the code in a debugger? If so, does `Product.prdUrl = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL` assign the correct value to `Product.prdUrl`?

Comment: i updated my some of my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, it should looks like this, works for me :D

```js
() => {
  // success
  this.productList.push({
    prdName: this.selectedProduct.prdName,
    prdCategory: this.selectedProduct.prdCategory,
    prdSup: this.selectedProduct.prdSup,
    prdDescription: this.selectedProduct.prdDescription,
    prdUrl: this.selectedProduct.prdUrl = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL,
    prdImage: this.selectedProduct.prdImage = Product.file.name,
  })

  this.saveFileData(Product)
}
```